# Pickle Problems in Python Trying to Save data and then add +1 to it each time it runs

Tags: python, pickle

Basically, I need some assistance to write a pickle file that starts with 1 and adds up each time I run it and saves the result. So after each run of the code it should save the previous result and add +1 each time it runs.

```
import pickle
os.system("clear")

filehandler = open("names.dat.txt","wb")
name = filehandler +1
pickle.dump(name,filehandler)
filehandler.close()

file = open("names.dat.txt",'rb')
object_file = pickle.load(file)
file.close()

print(object_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filehandler` is a file object, you shouldn't increment that. You want to increment the "*content*" of that file object.

How do you read the content of a pickled file? with `pickle.load()`.

I'm going to slightly modify your code:

```py
import os.path
import pickle


def read_number(path):
    # If there is no such file in your directory
    # instead of exception you assume it has value
    # of 0.
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        return 0
    with open(path, mode="rb") as f:
        return pickle.load(f)


def write_number(path):
    number = read_number(path)
    with open(path, mode="wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(number + 1, f)


os.system("clear")
filename = "names.dat.txt"

write_number(filename)
print(read_number(filename))
```